# Pig DUMP command hangs

Tags: apache-pig

This is what I'm trying

```
grunt> myData = load '/user/sunil/pigDev/player.csv' using PigStorage(',') AS (
                    id:int,
                    name:chararray,
                    age:int,
                    gender:chararray,
                    game:chararray,
                    location:chararray);

grunt> describe myData;
data: {id: int,name: chararray,age: int,gender: chararray,game: chararray,location: chararray}

grunt> dump myData;
```

It initializes and loads everything, creates jar as well(as I can see in the console logs). But, eventually hangs forever with the below log message in the console.

```
2015-06-10 18:32:30,163 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - 0% complete
```

I checked all log files(`nodemanager`,`proxyserver` and `yarn-resourcemanager`), don't see any error message.

I'm using CDH version : `Hadoop 2.5.0-cdh5.3.0`
Pig version : `Apache Pig version 0.12.0-cdh5.3.0 (rexported)`

Comment: Can you confirm the MapReduce job is actually getting started?

Comment: Hello Brandon, nope, its not getting started. I even tried to run a simple mapreduce wordcount program, but it also hangs with following message 
15/06/11 14:04:49 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_1434011594370_0001
The status of the job in the resource manager is as under
State : ACCEPTED
Final Status : UNDEFINED
Tracking URI : UNASSIGNED
I have assigned 2 gb of ram to nodemanage(yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb) got this suggestion [link]https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Batch-Processing-and-Workflow/Yarn-CDH5-gt-Stuck-in-runing-an-example-job-Starting-scan-to/td-p/21789